# ProfileService.svc endpoint ID different than in IIS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

On one of our environments, we can't figure out why the SP endpoints for the ProfileService.svc are listed at the following url for all 4 app servers:

Servername:32843/e56bbd2998ab4c65917c3ea0fe6d4f13/ProfileService.svc

Running:

```
$upsApp = Get-SPServiceApplication|?{$_.TypeName -eq "User Profile Service Application"};
$upsApp.EndPoints|%{Write-Host $_.ListenUris;}
```

Gives me the same results as above for the location.

Looking at IIS, that ID is where the ProfileDBCacheService.svc and ProfilePropertyService.svc resides.

ProfileService.svc is actually at e5b2e3955cc04be1a31b26cb1af1b9b3.

This has vexed me for a month.
UPSA has not been rebuilt.
The location where ProfileService.svc is located also contains NewsGator services which would leverage it.

Any insight to how this works is greatly appreciated.